# No ObservableObject of type found. environmentObject may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, environmentobject

I'm getting this Fatal Error for the `listViewModel`. Do I add the `@ObservableObject var listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel` to the `MakeMyOwnListView.swift` or `ManifestationMenuApp.swift` file?

Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type MakeMyOwnListViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for MakeMyOwnListViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

I'm confused about my understanding of ObservableObject and environmentObject any direction would be great.

MakeMyOwnListView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MakeMyOwnListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel
    // @ObservableObject var listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if listViewModel.items.isEmpty {
                MakeMyOwnNoItemsView()
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeIn))
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(listViewModel.items) { item in
                        MakeMyOwnListRowView(item: item)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                    listViewModel.updateItem(item: item)
                            }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: listViewModel.deleteItem)
                    .onMove(perform: listViewModel.moveItem)
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())

            }
        }
        // Navigation Title
        .navigationTitle("Make My Own ✍")
        // Navigation Butons
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: EditButton(),
            trailing:
                NavigationLink("Add", destination:
                                MakeMyOwnAddView())
        )
    }
    
}

struct MakeMyOwnListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Add NavigationView now we have the same environment in realtime when we are running our App
        NavigationView {
            MakeMyOwnListView()
        }
        .environmentObject(MakeMyOwnListViewModel())
    }
}
```

ManifestationMenuApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ManifestationMenuApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool = true
    
    @StateObject var listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel = MakeMyOwnListViewModel()
    
    // @ObservableObject var listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel
    // @EnvironmentObject var _listViewModel: MakeMyOwnListViewModel
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if isOnboarding {
                OnboardingView()
            } else {
                MainView()
                    .environmentObject(MenuListFriendshipViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListWealthViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListEducationViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListCareerViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListFamilyViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListHealthViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(MenuListSpiritualityViewModel())
            }
        }
        
        WindowGroup {
            // Now all are views will be in a Navigation View
            NavigationView {
                MakeMyOwnListView()
            }
            // iPad - A navigation view style represented by a view stack that only shows a single top view at a time.
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .environmentObject(MakeMyOwnListViewModel())
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image: MakeMyOwnListView.swift]

[image: ManifestationMenuApp.swift]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: in `ManifestationMenuApp`, try using `.environmentObject(listViewModel)` instead of
`.environmentObject(MakeMyOwnListViewModel())`

Comment: I get the same Fatal Error for `.environmentObject(listViewModel) `

Comment: if you can reach `MakeMyOwnListView()` from your `MainView()`,
 then try adding `.environmentObject(listViewModel)` to the `MainView()` in `ManifestationMenuApp` as well.